# Flutter Application Not Running in Release Mode but run in Debug and Profile

Tags: flutter, dart

i made an application with flutter and runned more than 10 times before last edits and **the last edits are nothing added new but somethings Iterative(no thing is new)** in release mode and produce application's without errors 
the problem is not giving any fault or error even when run

```
flutter run -v
```

what is the problem with flutter about all ?
 i have tried

```
flutter clean
```

without any good results
it only gives:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

this is the `flutter run -v`
log:**(last of it)**

```
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/draggable_scrollable_sheet.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_notification.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/fade_in_image.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_scope.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_traversal.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/gesture_detector.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/grid_paper.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/heroes.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon_data.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon_theme.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon_theme_data.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image_icon.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/inherited_model.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/inherited_theme.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/modal_barrier.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigation_toolbar.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/notification_listener.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/orientation_builder.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overscroll_indicator.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/pages.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/performance_overlay.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/placeholder.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/platform_view.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/preferred_size.dart
[   +1 ms] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/primary_scroll_controller.dart
[   +3 ms] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/raw_keyboard_listener.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/route_notification_messages.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/safe_area.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_activity.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_configuration.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_context.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart
[   +1 ms] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_metrics.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_physics.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.da
rt
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_simulation.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollable.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/semantics_debugger.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/shortcuts.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/size_changed_layout_notifier.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/sliver.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/sliver_layout_builder.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/sliver_persistent_header.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/sliver_prototype_extent_list.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/spacer.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/status_transitions.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/table.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/texture.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/title.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart
[   +1 ms] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tween_animation_builder.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/unique_widget.dart
[        ] ->
+file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/value_listenable_builder.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/viewport.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/visibility.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/widget_span.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart
[        ] -> +file:///C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/widgets.dart
[        ] -> 23afc489-318a-4a2d-907e-ac56ab8f5af7 build\app.dill 0
[        ] Updating files
[+1426 ms] DevFS: Sync finished
[   +2 ms] Syncing files to device D2502... (completed in 11,349ms, longer than expected)
[   +1 ms] Synced 1.9MB.
[   +1 ms] Sending to VM service: _flutter.listViews({})
[   +6 ms] Result: {type: FlutterViewList, views: [{type: FlutterView, id:
_flutterView/0xb857af90, isolate: {type: @Isolate, fixedId: true, id:
isolates/4097145620960107, name: main.dart$main-4097145620960107, number:
4097145620960107}}]}
[   +1 ms] <- accept
[        ] Connected to _flutterView/0xb857af90.
[   +6 ms] �  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild
state),
           press "R".
[  +63 ms] An Observatory debugger and profiler on D2502 is available at:
           http://127.0.0.1:56602/ug-EV7uiGhQ=/
[   +1 ms] For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit,
press "q".
```

**EDIT::**
when Running `flutter run --release`:

```
C:\FlutterApps\PrintTouch>flutter run --release
Initializing gradle...                                              2.0s
Resolving dependencies...                                           7.8s
Launching lib\main.dart on D2502 in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      79.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

**Edit 2:** when running `flutter build apk -v`

```
gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:765:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:505:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _AndroidBuilderImpl.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_builder.dart:101:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildApkCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:102:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
#6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#12     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#13     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

**EDIT#3:**
try running **flutter run --realease -v** ::

```
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:765:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:505:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _AndroidBuilderImpl.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_builder.dart:101:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:485:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:438:46)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:63:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:460:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
#9      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#12     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#15     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#17     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#18     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#19     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#22     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#23     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#24     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#25     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#26     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#27     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#28     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
#29     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#30     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#31     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#32     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#33     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#34     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#35     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#36     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#37     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#38     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#39     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#40     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#41     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#42     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#43     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

Comment: Try running.. flutter run - - release

Comment: @VidorVistrom it gave the same answer i posted it as edit to the post

Comment: Did you make changes in native code?

Comment: Changes like app icon or in gradle?

Comment: @VidorVistrom no no .. as i told in the post above i added something iterative..and runned before on old versions

Comment: There could be several reasons.. kotlin version, app icon change, or gradle

Comment: @VidorVistrom i havent changed any of the above

Comment: @VidorVistrom is there any tool to know where is the errror?

Comment: flutter build apk -v

Comment: @VidorVistrom i posted the answer as edit 2 , i couldnt understand where is the error

Comment: Okay try running flutter run --release -v

Comment: also do check flutter doctor I smell some broken packages

Comment: @VidorVistrom flutter doctor tested firslty no problems , but for run release -v i posted an edit 3 to the post

Comment: Hmm.. Its really hard to detect such an issue. How about you  move to channel stable by "flutter channel stable" and then flutter upgrade? And could you also list the exact same changes that you made since it became not operational?

Comment: Also do check for the internet permissions in the android manifest

Comment: @Vidor,  I am avoiding flutter upgrade because it causes alot of problems,  seems it is the last solution -_-,

Comment: I returned the code from code history to before changes it gave the same error,   I discovered that the problem is with gradle -_-

Comment: Internet permission is already checked and every thing is OK

Comment: So the problem is resolved?

Comment: No I need to upgrade the flutter to know

Comment: But known that the code added is correct the problem circle is reduced but not defined

Comment: @VidorVistrom the flutter upgrade made alot of error inside the code and enforce it to support androidx and made alot of problems , why is upgrading in flutter is so Hard!!!

Comment: @It won't make it tough if you constantly keepnthe flutter engine up to date. And android x migration is necessary for some of the packages that you might be using externally. You must be running a pretty older version of flutter!

Comment: No it was the last version of flutter before this,  but not enforcing the app to be android x supported!

Comment: So are you having trouble migrating to Android X?

Comment: no not this, the problem is with gradle and it's sdk i dont know why